# Retrieving Custom Exception from Asp.Net Web API to Postman

Tags: exception, asp.net-web-api2, postman

We have created Custom Exception class and it has some information which we need return from Web API. Right now when we return data to Postman, Custom Exception gets overridden by Base Exception class.

This is output we are getting now:

[image]

And, this information we need in postman.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are mistakening in the implementation of your custom class. Below is sample implementation of custom exception class.

```
 public class APIExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
            public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
               {
                     // Assign the status code that you want as output
                       HttpStatusCode status = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                       string messageToBeDisplayed = "TestMessage";
                       actionExecutedContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = status, Content = new StringContent( messageToBeDisplayed , System.Text.Encoding.UTF8) };
                       base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);

               }
    }
```

Inside your "WebApiConfig" class and "Register" method, you need to add "APIExceptionFilter" filters like below as it will register it for all requests:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
              // Add this......
              config.Filters.Add(new APIExceptionFilter());
        }
    }
```

Comment: @sumit Please accept the answer if you find it useful